# When does the top users statistics get updated?

Tags: support, bug

I have been watching my status on the top users group for the tags that I frequent. I have answered many questions and gotten several upvotes. However, I noticed that my stats is unchanged in the top users page. The numbers and my standing seem to have not changed for a while now. A friend told me those things get updated daily. Is that still the case? Maybe a bug?

Comment: See the answer on [this question over at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213993/what-scripts-run-at-300-utc)

Comment: The top users says you have a score of 12.  You have a score of 13 when looking at posts more than a day old, so presumably one of those votes on older answers is recent.  Looks right to me.  I don't see any indication that it's several days old.

Comment: There is a 12 and an 8 next to my name in the top users in the SAS tag. I answered 13 and had several more upvotes. I may not be understanding the way these things are done but how is the person that has a 12 6 at a higher level than me. Why isn't my score being update to 13? And doesn't the upvotes amount to anything in the top users statistics?

Comment: Normally those lists are updated once a day, but I also recognized this is not happening lately, at least not regularly.

Comment: Finally, the stats were updated and my numbers are now accurate. I am now certain that the updates are not daily.

Comment: I've noticed this too.  Not sure how often it updates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, stats traditionally have been updated daily, with occasional lapses. Those occasional lapses have been frequent lately.

If you want to see updated stats before the scripts run, @awesome-poodles created a page that lets you query points by site and user.

Near real-time tag scores by site and user:
http://jsbin.com/azeqec/12

Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179402/180794