# Contradiction between Top User statistics and ranking on profile

Tags: bug

**Note:** Before anyone points this out, no, I'm not into the competition aspect of this at all, and yes, I am aware that rep is basically unicorn points. I'm not worried about comparing how many fake Internet points I have to how many other people have; my main point here is to point out the discrepancy.

According to the [User Reputation League](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/4032703#4032703), I am #22,106 in the all-time reputation league at 10,369 rep. (This is actually 10 points behind, but that's likely due to caching). Also, according to the statistics on the sidebar, there are a total of 34,264 users with 10k+ reputation and 14,331,410 users total. Based on being #22,106, I would be in the top 0.15% of users overall. However, my user profile states that I'm in the top 4% overall:

[image]

Is the 4% just woefully out-of-date caching, or is this a defect? How often is this updated?

Also, are there actually 12,158 users who have a reputation between 10,000 and 10,368? That would imply that over 35% of users who are over 10k are over 10k by 368 or less, which seems odd. (I admittedly have not run a SEDE query for this one).

I have seen [this Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253292/when-does-the-top-users-statistics-get-updated), but it's almost 7 years old (so it's probably out-of-date by now) and it doesn't really explain why my profile page is so out-of-date (because my profile is much more than a day behind).

Comment: The note under the table on the right side of the page states that "* users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues". So, 22106/666763 (users over 200 rep.) is 0.033, which makes you in the top 3.3%, hence the top 4%.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille That seems like a reasonable explanation. What should I do with this question?

Comment: It's up to you. It seems like a reasonable question, and could be answered. You could also see it as No Repro and that it should be closed. If you don't think the question is useful to anyone else, you can go ahead and delete it, since there aren't any answers yet.